# Windows services "sandbox"

Tags: c#, windows-services

We are faced with the problem maintaining lots of windows services. 
The idea is to reorganize windows services in to class libraries and connect libraries to one master windows service. Is there a good idea ? Any advices please)

Comment: This is pretty broad.  Perhaps you could give us some more information about the problem you are having/trying to solve.  Are you just asking about general project organization?

Comment: A big red flag I would see is that if that service goes down, then all your functionality goes down. What do these services do?

Comment: We are looking for decision of maintaining all windows services concerning the particular project. We need to know service state (online/offline) and e-mail administrator if service is down e.t.c  Services are prepare and transfer data from database or recieve  data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a framework for hosting "services" within a single Windows Service called TopShelf.  You might want to consider using that.  https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf

Answer (score 1):

I am interpreting your question to be "We have tons of little Windows applications that run as services - how can we simplify them?".

In general, lots of smaller programs are better.  Single monolithic applications are difficult to maintain and test; when someone needs to make a small change it can trigger catastrophic consequences for dozens of other components of the application.  It can also make it impossible to change one small application without taking down the whole service, as Chris Knight comments above.

On the other hand, lots of small programs suffer from the breadth problem.  You probably want to make sure all your little programs run on a consistent framework - i.e. they all log their results to the same place, they all use a standardized configuration system, and they are all managed in the same place.

I have seen situations where people write services because they need to run a task "when a particular condition happens", so they make it a constantly running service and continuously check for that condition.  Is it possible that you could take some of your services and turn them into triggered launches of individual applications?

If this isn't the correct interpretation, please let me know :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Yes, we have extremely growing project ) that involves various technologies. We should connect one web system to another different system using web services, but also we need something, for example, to start transfer data or transfer and convert data in to another format of another system.

Comment: that's why we are looking for a maintenance decision

Comment: For triggering tasks, I tend to like using a simple task wrapper like the Windows Task Scheduler or some other program like http://www.acelet.com/super/SuperScheduler/ .  You can also write a tiny little web app and give it buttons to spawn off certain tasks, if they are triggered manually.